# gorm AutoMigrate() add new primaryKey not woring

Tags: go, go-gorm

```golang
type Passport struct {
    Uid         int64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ...
}
```

i used
`dbMain.Set("gorm:table_options", "CHARSET=utf8mb4").AutoMigrate(new(Passport))`
to created a table;

```
type Passport struct {
    Uid         int64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Type        int   `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ...
}
```

and then i changed my struct, wanna use `AutoMigrate()` to build composite primary key;
but not working
btw `gorm:"not null` is useful